# EmberFire Adding relationship from different model

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

```
-------------------------------
Ember      : 1.13.11
Ember Data : 1.13.15
Firebase   : 2.3.2
EmberFire  : 1.6.3
jQuery     : 1.11.3
-------------------------------
```

I've got two endpoints in my firebase app. `/employees` and `/subjects`. In my ember app I want to add subjects to an employee (`employees/$id/subjects`). The problem is, I don't know how to load all my subjects from `/subjects` so I can add them to my array.

This is my routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('dashboard');
  this.route('employees', function() {
    this.route('employee', { path: '/:id'});
  });
});
```

And this is my model

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('employee', params.id);
    }
});
```

I've tried various things to get this to work, creating a subroute `this.route(employee, function(){ this.route('subjects') }`, loading a second model in my employee model, none of which has worked. I'm new to ember so I might have gotten some things mixed up. Any helps is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Employee model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  position: DS.attr('string'),
  accessoryPosition: DS.attr('string'),
  education: DS.attr('string'),
  experience: DS.attr('string'),
  imgUrl: DS.attr('string'),
  subjects: DS.hasMany('subject', {async: true})
});
```

Subject Model

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

To maybe describe my intentions a bit better, here is the flow I want:

User selects an employee, employees info is shown along with a list of subjects assigned to that employee. But I also need the full list of subjects available, if I want to assign a new subject to an employee. Hence my question. Hope this makes sense

Comment: if you want to get all `subjects`, have you tried `this.store.findAll('subject')` ?

Comment: also, post your employee and subjects model files, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, then you can do this in your Route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model(params) {
     return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            employee: this.store.findRecord('employee', params.id), 
            subjects: this.store.findAll('subject')        
     });
  }
});
```

then in your template:

```
{{#each employee.subjects as |subject|}}
   {{!these are your employee subjects}}
   {{subject.name}}
{{/each}}



{{#each subjects as |subject|}}
   {{!these are all your subjects}}
   {{subject.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: When I do this, then my child template employee isn't loading. Even if I take the {{#if model.isLoaded}} out it still doesn't display it?